# C# обобщения vs object

Tags: c#, объекты, generics

```
 class GenericClass<T>
{
    T val;
    public T value
    {
        get
        {
            return val;
        }
        set
        {
            val = value;
        }
    }
}


class ObjectClass
{
    object val;
    public object value
    {
        get
        {
            return val;
        }
        set
        {
            val = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Какая разница между этими двумя класами? Что в первом универсальный тип данных - что во втором. Более того, насколько я знаю, компилятор тип данных T все равно приводит к типу object.

Comment: _насколько я знаю, компилятор тип данных T все равно приводит к типу object_ - не в C#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Универсальные шаблоны (или же обощения) в C# вводят концепцию параметров универсального типа. Благодаря им можно создавать классы и методы с типами, спецификация которых отложена до момента объявления и создания экземпляров в клиентском коде.

```
class GenericClass<T>
{
    T val;
    public T value
    {
        get { return val; }
        set { val = value; }
    }
}
```

У вас показан класс с параметром T универсального типа (обычно такие подходы используют для работы с коллекциями, причем чаще всего их использут совместно с заданичем ограничения с помощью `where`, которое включают в себя все ограничения базового типа `T`). Этот класс может использоваться в другом клиентском коде, не требуя ресурсов и не создавая рисков, связанных с операциями приведения и упаковки-преобразования в среде выполнения. Универсальные классы могут вносить некое ограничение типов (когда мы напишем конструкцию `where`), то есть они разрешают доступ только для определенных типов данных. Что дает основополагающий плюс и видимый выйгрыш.

Однако следующий код:

```
class ObjectClass
{
    object val;
    public object value
    {
        get { return val; }
        set { val = value; }
    }
}
```

Несет на борту определенный тип (пусть это `object`, но ведь он определенный, хоть и наследуется всеми типами), что в свою очередь приведет к операциями приведения и упаковки-преобразования. Что повлечет за собой трату ресурсов (ну и времени конечно же). Иными словами это ведет к потере безопасности типов и понижению производительности, когда универсальные шаблоны этой проблемы не имеют.

Если выбирать между универсальными шаблонами и `object` - я бы несомненно выбрал универсальные шаблоны (обобщения).

Ну и для справки будет полезно:

- [Универсальные шаблоны](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)
- [object](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/object)